# SignalR not working unless tested from github source

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

I have a simple signalR notification sender ASP.net 4.0 website. The website when run from visual studio does not work, no matter how much online solutions are used.

```
$.connection.<myClassName>
```

returns no object(source:JS debug in FF). But when I run the `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.JS.Tests` from visual studio, the whole system i.e. my website starts working.

I have to do this on every OS restart.
Can any one help me in understanding, why this happens. Is there a possible workaround ?

PS it throws an error sth like 'reference type not found', i have a hint now that signalR/hubs is not generated in first situation

Comment: does /signalr/hubs return something reasonable?

Comment: no it doesn't(unless the solution applied) and i can not seem to tell why?

Comment: if it throws an error, maybe update your post

Comment: Now it is not working even with my workaround :(

Answer (score 0):

reinstalling then adding in global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

with

```
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

has helped probably, at least issue is solved for now :)